# CURL 's readback function

Tags: curl, libcurl

```
    const char data[]="this is what we post to the silly web server";

    struct WriteThis {
      const char *readptr;
      long sizeleft;
    };
    static size_t read_callback(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void *userp)
    {
      struct WriteThis *pooh = (struct WriteThis *)userp;

      if(size*nmemb < 1)
        return 0;

      if(pooh->sizeleft) {
        *(char *)ptr = pooh->readptr[0]; /* copy one single byte */ 
        pooh->readptr++;                 /* advance pointer */ 
        pooh->sizeleft--;                /* less data left */ 
        return 1;                        /* we return 1 byte at a time! */ 
      }

      return 0;                          /* no more data left to deliver */ 
    }

 struct WriteThis pooh;

  pooh.readptr = data;
  pooh.sizeleft = (long)strlen(data);
     curl = curl_easy_init();
      if(curl) {
        /* First set the URL that is about to receive our POST. */ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/index.cgi");

        /* Now specify we want to POST data */ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);

        /* we want to use our own read function */ 
        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READFUNCTION, read_callback);



    };
```

I do not see how the parameters of read_callback ()  got initialized. ptr, size and nmmemb and usurp.

Comment: I would urge you to read the CURLOPT_READFUNCTION documentation as it describes all this: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_READFUNCTION.html

Answer (score 2):

As the CURL document says, `read_callback` is a callback function which gets called by libcurl as soon as it needs to read data in order to send it to the peer. `size_t nmemb` indicates the size curl has reserved for a single chunk of data, the last `void* userp` is a pointer which was set by `CURLOPT_READDATA` option, so you need add this line in your code:

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, &pooh);
```

And don't forget to call `curl_easy_perform(curl)` at last.